# Return only value in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the task to write a program to find the cheapest route. The only problem is, that the car has a gas tank and needs to refuel. So I came up with the Idea to write a recursive function to simulate the refueling process and compare the resulting prices. The Code looks like this:

```
    calcCheapest() {
    const routeBuilder = (curRoute, curPrice, curLiter) => {

        let curStation = curRoute[curRoute.length - 1];

        let newReachables = this.route[curStation].reachables;

        if (!newReachables.length) {
            if (curPrice < cheapestPrice) {
                return { curRoute: curRoute, curPrice: curPrice };
            } else {
                return { curRoute: [], curPrice: Infinity};
            }
        }

        else return newReachables.map(reachable => {

            // multiple comparisons on how to refule

            return routeBuilder([...curRoute, reachable], newPrice, newLiters)
        })
    }


    var cheapestPrice = Infinity;

    var a = routeBuilder([this.start], 0, this.curLiter);
    console.log(a);

}
```

But my resulting "a" variable is:

```
    (6)[
    0: (6)[
        0: (6)[
            0: (6)[
                0: (5)[
                    ...... 
                        [
                            curPrice: 271271.03, curRoute: Array(11)[0, 194, 1305, … ]
                        ]
                    …]
                …]
            …]
        …]
    …]
```

And I don't know how to only return the values.. If I take away the return in front of the map my resulting "a" is undefined.

Comment: Store that array in a variable. Look for the best one. Then return that.

Comment: Since you did not add a runnable example I can't be sure, but it seems that the `return newReachables.map` should be `return newReachables.flatMap`